# Procedure of Australian Medical Council exam for foreigners from South Asia

Tags: health-education, different-national-health

My friend is a MBBS student from Bangladesh. She is currently in her 3rd year and is willing to sit for AMC exam after graduation. But we don't know about the correct procedure to apply and sit for exam yet.So it would be of great help if someone could help with providing the way of procedure.